# how to make jquery react when class changes

Tags: jquery, class, alter

I have a simple Tab Navigation with jquery. Whenever a new tab is clicked, the script adds to the current navigation list element the class "currentNav" and deletes it from the previous selected list element. Now I want to change the background of the mother ul whenever the second list element gets the class "currentNav". The start default is that the first list element has this class. My problem is, I don't know how I can make jquery react on that change..

Here is the html of the navigation

```
<ul id="AuktionenNav">
                    <li><a class="tabSelect one currentNav" href="#Tab0" rel="0">Auktionen starten</a></li>
                    <li><a class="tabSelect two" href="#Tab1" rel="1">Eingestellte Auktionen</a></li>
                </ul>
```

And here my jquery so far

```
if($("ul#AuktionenNav li a.two").hasClass("currentNav")) {
        $("ul#AuktionenNav").css("background-image", "url(../system/css/images/eingestellte_Auktionen.png)")
    }
```

I appreciate any help! Thx!

Comment: With jQuery, you can just add it to the `toggleClass` code, can we see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a trigger and a bind:

```
// When an <li> (NOT the first one) is clicked, tell the <ul>
$('ul#AuktionenNav li').not(':first-child').click(function(){ 
    $(this).trigger('li_clicked'); 
});

// When the FIRST <li> is clicked, reset the background
$('ul#AuktionenNav li:first-child').click(function(){ 
    $('ul#AuktionenNav').css("background-image", "url(../system/css/images/default.png)");
});
// Listen for an <li> click
$('ul#AuktionenNav').bind('li_clicked',function(){
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(../system/css/images/eingestellte_Auktionen.png)");
});
```

I know your example only has two `<li>` tags, but this will scale easily while keeping the first `<li>` the "resetter"

Comment: thx! it works perfect.. but one more question, how can I get the default background-image back if someone clicks again on the first li element?

Comment: Thank you very much!! I had to exchange the "this" in the section with the li:first-child with ul#AuktionenNav but now it works perfect! I really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Missed that in the c/p. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to use the DOM mutation events:

```
$('ul').bind('DOMSubtreeModified',

function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').addClass('red');
});

$('#toggle').click(
    function(){
        $('ul li:nth-child(2)').toggleClass('highlight');
        return false;
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bBBrb/).

Answer (score 0):

### [HERE IS A DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/gsACP/)

```
$('ul#AuktionenNav li a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('currentNav');
    if ($("ul#AuktionenNav li a.two").hasClass("currentNav")) {
        $("ul#AuktionenNav").css("background-image", "url(../system/css/images/eingestellte_Auktionen.png")
    }
});
```

Comment: A demo of *what*? Please bring your code in-line with the question and answer.

Comment: Thanks David... I was just adding it, wait still 15 sec.

Comment: @Sebsemillia glad you make it work! Happy coding and don't forget to take a coffe break sometimes! ;)